# SQL Query to IQueryable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, iqueryable

I would like to ask if how could i convert this SQL Query to a IQueryable:

SQL Query:

> ```
>   SELECT 
>     [s].[Id] AS [Id], 
>     [s].[PartId] AS [PartId], 
>     [s].[Quantity] AS [Quantity], 
>     [s].[OfficeId] AS [OfficeId], 
>     [s].[StockLocationId] AS [StockLocationId], 
>     [s].[StockSubLocationId] AS [StockSubLocationId],
>     [p].[Description] AS [PartDescription],
>     [p].[StdSellPrice] AS [PartSellPrice]
>     FROM [dbo].[Stock] AS [s]
>     INNER JOIN [dbo].[Part] AS p ON [p].Id = [s].PartId
>     WHERE ([s].[StockLocationId] >= 1) AND ([s].[StockSubLocationId] <= 2)
> ```

So far i have got to this IQueryable:

```
var getStockDetails = tempCtx.Stocks.Where(s => s.StockLocationId >= loc && s.StockSubLocationId <= subLoc);
```

Comment: What are `loc` and `subloc`? Why did you change from constants to variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var getStockDetails = 
    from s in tempCtx.Stocks
    join p in tempCtx.Part on s.PartId equals p.Id
    where s.StockLocationId >= 1 and s.StockSubLocationId <= 2
    select new { Id = s.Id, PartId = s.PartId, Quantity = s.Quantity };
```

Just add on the select part for the other columns you want returned.

Comment: both of the answer are correct. but what should be the best to use?

Comment: I would have to agree with shree.pat18, go with the one you're comfortable with. Both answers gets the job done. :)

Comment: Ok thanks guys. i answer this because its much readable. @shree.pat18

Comment: just a question. how come you used >= and <=? i was expecting a ==.

Comment: I used those because those are what you used in the SQL query. `WHERE ([s].[StockLocationId] >= 1) AND ([s].[StockSubLocationId] <= 2)` I was not sure what you were really after in terms of data retrieval.

Comment: if i use those i will get the value graterthan or equal to 1 and lessthan or equal to 2 right? but i want just equal with the specific parameter.

Comment: if you use those, you will get `StockLocationId` greater than or equal to one and `StockSubLocationId` is less than or equal to two. Those are two different fields you're filtering on. If you want just a specific "parameter" then change it to `where s.[whateverColumnName] == paramValue`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var q = tempCtx.Stocks.
            Join(tempCtx.Parts, x => x.PartID, y => y.ID, (x,y) => new{x=x,y=y}).
            Where(xy=>xy.x.StockLocationID >= 1 && xy.x.StockSubLocationID <= 2).
            Select(xy => new {
                              xy.x.ID, 
                              xy.x.PartID, 
                              xy.x.Quantity, 
                              xy.x.OfficeID, 
                              xy.x.StockLocationID, 
                              xy.x.StockSubLocationID, 
                              xy.y.Description, 
                              xy.y.StdSellPrice});
```

Comment: both of the answer are correct. but what should be the best to use?

Comment: Depends on what you are comfortable with. I prefer to use LINQ with Lambdas in C# rather than the SQL-style syntax. Not really sure it would matter performance wise, but you'd better confirm that part. Check this link for more perspectives on the matter: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/24940/does-the-usage-of-linq-and-lambda-expressions-lead-to-less-readable-code

Comment: could you give me a sample of this code using multiple joins?